# How to configure IP address and domain of a VM using HyperV v1 WMI classes?

Tags: windows, hyper-v, hypervisor

How can we configure IP address and domain of a VM using HyperV v1 WMI classes?

In HyperV v2 it is possible with "SetGuestNetworkAdapterConfiguration" WMI class but couldn't find any such class in v1.

Answer (score 0):

In v1 there is no such class Msvm_GuestNetworkAdapterConfiguration.
You can set vm's ip using Msvm_KvpExchangeDataItem. A powered on VM has an associator of type Msvm_KvpExchangeComponent which has property of type String array called "GuestIntrinsicExchangeItems". This array contains embedded instances of Msvm_KvpExchangeDataItem and one of them is for configuring IP address. You are interested in the one that has the following fragment:

```
<PROPERTY NAME="Name" TYPE="string">
    <VALUE>NetworkAddressIPv4</VALUE>
</PROPERTY>
```

In the same embedded instance there is the IP address of the vm's network adapter, and it looks like this:

```
<PROPERTY NAME="Data" TYPE="string">
    <VALUE>192.168.0.101</VALUE>
</PROPERTY>
```

For more information how to manage Msvm_KvpExchangeDataItem instances look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg196297%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)